# Allure2 report not using allure.properties for @Issue

Tags: allure

In my current setup I have it so that I can have a static allure.properties file located in my allure-results folder.  This properties file holds the value for the `@Issue` environment variable and value.

`allure.link.issue.pattern=https\://tfs.mytfs.com/tfs/_workitems?id\={}`

When I generate the report `allure generate --clean <results dir> -o <report dir>` it does not appear to be using the `allure.properties` file to populate the `@Issue` links with the correct value.  Instead, the link value is blank and the link redirects to itself.

I am using the updated `@Issue` environment variable.  I think this might be due to how I am generating the report as the documentation states "simply generate the report. By default command-line tool looking for config in the directory you run the command. You can use ALLURE_CONFIG environment variable to specify the path to configuration".

I am not sure what I am missing though as I run the generate command from the results folder.  Is that not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version Allure 2 no need to pass `allure.properties` file to `allure-results` folder. You need to add it to your test resources instead.

Here you can find an example https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-testng-example/blob/master/src/test/resources/allure.properties